# What is Authentication server URL in OAuth 2.0 that is needed to be passed to get the access token automatically?

Tags: oauth

Can someone tell what is the authentication server URL and resource server URL in OAuth 2.0 that which is used for generating the Access Token Automatically in google cloud services.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don&#39;t know Google Cloud Services, but in general is the authentication server the server that&#39;s giving you the token and the resource server the server that you want to access.

Comment: try to play with this google playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ the server is "google accounts" and the resource is the service you are interested in.